# Window can not find catalina.bat, even catalina is exist

Tags: windows, tomcat, filesystems

When I try start tomcat in IDEA it gives me the below error message:

> Error running Tomcat 8.0.35: Cannot run program
>   "D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\bin\catalina.bat" (in directory
>   "D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The
>   system cannot find the file specified

The weird thing is that I can run catalina.bat from a command line, but the Windows graphical user interface does not work：

[Error message from Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7usog.jpg)

[CMD and other info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GadxY.jpg)

As we see, catalina.bat exists and the authority is also ok but just cannot run it.

Could someone check this and provide some suggestions?

BTW, all Tomcat's bat files can run from the CMD line but they give me the same "not exist" error given in the graphic interface.

Comment: Could you please also include a screenshot of General tab of the file properties from Explorer?

Comment: General tab for bat file and BIN folder：

[General tab](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KbNRE.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Follow **"My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment Variables" > "Path"** and add *"D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\bin"* to your PATH variable please.

Comment: I don't think this is PATH issue, cause in command line bat still working,        and I already add JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME and CATALINA_HOME in "Environment Variables", you can check [CMD and other info] img.

Comment: @MingLiu It take 2 minutes to test anyhow

Comment: ok,but I am not near that computer, will try your way latter.

Comment: Tomcat folder is in PATH variable, still come out "not exist" error